# Non-primary key column value oriented auto increment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It was hard for me to describe the problem in the title. But I'm looking should actually be very trivial.

Having such a table:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id | club_id | member_id | name   |
├-----------------------------------┤
| 1  | 120     | 1         | Thomas |
| 2  | 83      | 1         | Robert |
| 3  | 120     | 2         | James  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**id** *- auto-incrementing primary key*
**club_id** *- foreign key reference*
**member_id** *- auto-incrementing for each club*
**name** *- just an example for data*

So I think what I want is clear. It's like having a members table with auto incrementing id, just that every "club" in my app can have members.

Does a database-solution for this even exist or would I need to provide this from my application?

Comment: There is a lot of server-side solutions. The best solution (in my opinion) is do NOT create member_id at all, store record creation time and calculate this "number in the club" in data retrieving query. Of course records are deleted never, they may be set as non-actual only.

Comment: PS. If you'll decide to store this field in the structure do not forget to create unique index by `(club_id, member_id)`. PPS. What is the reason in synthetic `id` as PK whereas this composite key is good candidate for PK? of course when one man cannot be a member of 2 or more clubs - but in this case your structure is de-normalized.

Comment: MyISAM supports this behaviour, but I agree with the above; just store a regular AI for users, and separately record which user belongs to which club.

Comment: Presumably, you have a `members` table and a `clubs` table.  The `name` should not be in this table.